# $\mathbf{A}^1$-invariance of Brauer groups and $H^2_{\mathrm{et}}(-;\mathbb{G}_m)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

The $\mathbf{A}^1$-invariance of vector bundles have been discussed in, for example, [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-166/issue-10/Affine-representability-results-in-A1-homotopy-theory-I--Vector/10.1215/00127094-0000014X.short) by Asok, Hoyois and Wendt. This of course implies storng $\mathbf{A}^1$-invariance results for the first etale cohomology group $H^1_{\mathrm{et}}(-,\mathbb{G}_m)$. Are there any similar results for $H_{\mathrm{et}}^2(-,\mathbb{G}_m)$ or the Brauer groups?

Comment: For a field $k$ and an element $a$ in $k^\times/(k^\times)^p$, have you considered the cyclic algebra over $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ coming from $a$ and the Artin-Schreier cover of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?  More generally, have you looked at the $p$-torsion in the Brauer group of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ realized via Kato's isomorphism (using differential forms and inverse Cartier)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(For $i=0$, the map $H_{\mathrm{et}}^{0}(\operatorname{Spec} A,\mathbb{G}_{m}) \to H_{\mathrm{et}}^{0}(\operatorname{Spec} A[t],\mathbb{G}_{m})$ is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ is reduced.)

For $i=1$, it is a theorem of Traverso that $H_{\mathrm{et}}^{1}(\operatorname{Spec} A,\mathbb{G}_{m}) \to H_{\mathrm{et}}^{1}(\operatorname{Spec} A[t],\mathbb{G}_{m})$ is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ is seminormal.

For $i=2$, at least when $A$ is a field, the map $H_{\mathrm{et}}^{2}(\operatorname{Spec} A,\mathbb{G}_{m}) \to H_{\mathrm{et}}^{2}(\operatorname{Spec} A[t],\mathbb{G}_{m})$ is an isomorphism if and only if $A$ is perfect; thus if $A$ is regular with perfect fraction field we have a similar positive result (see Auslander, Goldman, *The Brauer group of a commutative ring*, ([link](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1960-097-03/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6/S0002-9947-1960-0121392-6.pdf)) 7.5, 7.7 respectively). In general (for the torsion at least) we only have to worry about the $p$-torsion for primes $p$ that are not invertible in $A$. There are some additional positive results in Knus, Ojanguren, *A Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the Brauer group* ([link](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82736669.pdf)) Theorem 3.6 and I'd be interested in a more complete characterization.

Comment: The condition that $A$ is perfect precisely eliminates the elements $a$ in my comment.  For a field $k$ of characteristic $p$ such that $k^\times/(k^\times)^p$ is nontrivial, the $p$-torsion in the Brauer group of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ does not equal the $p$-torsion in the Brauer group of $k$.  Kato's isomorphism should also give information about the $p$-torsion in higher degree cohomology of $\mathbb{G}_m$.